# Increasing font size of help text

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2019

If I hover the mouse over a .NET function in a C# file I get a popup window showing some documentation:

[image]

I'd like to increase the font size of this text.

There are many items in the `Fonts and Colors` section of the options:

[image]

Which of these can be used to increase this font size?

(This is one thing I like about vscode over VS; increasing the font size there with `ctrl-+` applies to pretty much all text in the application. :-))

Comment: Can't answer the question but please tag the specific version of visual studio you are using as options may differ between versions.

Comment: @phuzi Added! Thanks for the suggestion.

Answer (score 1):

Try "Editor Tooltip".
[image: Tools --> Options --> Fonts and Color]